# What type of product am I submitting for security review?

Tags: security-review

I am about to submit my Salesforce package (2GP) for security review, and clicking "Start Review" in the Partner Community portal prompts me with a choice:

```
What type of product are you submitting?
( ) App, Bolt Solution, Flow, Lightning Data, Component and Consultant
( ) Component
```

But I can't find any documentation on what the difference is. The fact that `Component` appears in both choices is also confusing.

Comment: If you have more than one type of metadata it is probably what would be called an App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, I was trying to upload my package on the wrong page.

I had gone to `Publishing` > `Packages` (https://partners.salesforce.com/publisherPackages)

The page I needed to use was `Publishing` > `Listings` > [Click listing] > `App` > `Select Package` ([https://partners.salesforce.com/listingSolution?listingId={id}](https://partners.salesforce.com/listingSolution?listingId=%7Bid%7D))

Then, I was able to select a package. (Although, getting to that point was a whole other ordeal.)

Answer (score -1):

Before you submit your solution for security review:

- Receive Salesforce approval of your business plan.
- Have a partner recruitment representative confirm that your solution
  is enrolled in the AppExchange Partner Program, and that you have a
  distribution agreement.
- Create your AppExchange solution listing in the Partner Community
  Publishing Console. If your solution includes a package, connect your
  packaging org to the Publishing Console and upload the package.
- Configure a Developer Edition test environment with your solution
  installed. We use the environment to test your solution.
- Certify that your solution is Lightning Ready. All new solutions
  submitted for security review must be Lightning Ready

1. Log in to the [Salesforce Partner Community](https://partners.salesforce.com/pdx/s/?language=en_US&redirected=RGSUDODQUL).
2. Navigate to the Business Plan tab of your solution listing in the
   Publishing Console.
3. Verify that your business plan is approved.
4. If your plan is approved, click the solution-type tab. The tab name
   corresponds to the type of solution you’re listing: App, Component,
   Flow, and so on.
5. Provide solution details.
6. If your solution includes a package, click `Select Package`, then find
   and select the managed package version that you plan to list. If you
   can’t find the package to associate with your listing, check that
   the packaging org is connected to the Publishing Console.
7. Save your changes.
8. On the Security Review tab, click `Start Review`. You’re guided
   through the options and settings that require your input, based on
   the solution type.
9. On the Payment page, select an option for Pricing. Your selection
   must match the selection on the listing’s Pricing tab.

   a. If you plan to sell your solution on AppExchange, select `Paid` and enter
   payment information. Solutions that require payment later, such as `free`
   downloads, free installs, and pay-per-use are considered paid.

   b. If you plan to distribute your solution for free, select Free. We don’t
   charge security review or annual listing fees for solutions that are
   distributed for free on AppExchange.
10. Click `Submit`.

Refer the [Submit Your Solution for Security Review](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/security_review_submit_solution.htm)

Refer the [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/appexchange-solutions/tour-solutions-by-type) module with clear explanation about solution type.